# Updating info.plist file of framework project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7-beta3

I am having one sub-project[.xcodeproject folder] inside the main project. I want to update the info.plist file of the sub-project, but I am not able to find it. When I open the sub-project as the main project, and see the Info tab of it, I don't see table with Key, Type, Value columns but instead they have 3 sections - Deployment Target, Configurations, Localizations.

Can anyone help me with it?
The main project is using iOS9 beta and Xcode 7.0 beta 3, but the framework project which I am putting inside the main project was originally written for some older iOS versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the "Info" section of the target. This is ***not*** the same thing as the Info.plist file, although there is a connection (app identifier, target version, etc). What you are looking for a **file** Info.plist. This is usually found under the "Supporting Files" sub-folder in the target project. Try expanding this folder. If you still cannot find it, try searching the project for it or open the project in Finder and look for it there. If you ***still*** cannot find it, this means that something has gone wrong and I would say recreate it.

Hope this helps!